# SQL : Count(*) and groupby with different table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables as shown below.

First Table `tblCategory`

[image]

Second Table `tblWord`

[image]

`Required Output`

[image]

On output,

`TotalCount` is `count(*)` with `group by categoryid` from `tblWord`

`Played` is `count(*)` with `where isPlayed = 1 group by categoryid` from `tblword`

So for getting result from 2 table, I tried following query which is wrong.

```
select (select count(*) from tblwords group by categoryid) as count, (select count(*) from tblwords where isPlayed = 1 group by categoryid) as played, categoryID, categoryname from tblcategory
```

Any suggestion in query to get required output or any helpful links ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get exact output with total count

```
SELECT t.categoryID, t.name,
       COUNT(*) as TotalCount, SUM(isplayed) as Played
FROM tblCategory t
INNER JOIN tblWord tw
ON t.categoryID = tw.categoryID
GROUP BY t.categoryID, t.name
```

To get count for isPlayed = 1 only

```
SELECT t.categoryID, t.name,
       COUNT(*) as TotalCount, SUM(isplayed) as Played
FROM tblCategory t
INNER JOIN tblWord tw
ON t.categoryID = tw.categoryID
WHERE isPlayed=1
GROUP BY t.categoryID, t.name
```

Comment: @m hasan can we get only isPlayed=1 records by using above query ?

Comment: @mhasan : isPlayed is bool... but I really amazed that we can apply sum(). Got exact output. And Learned new thing "sum" :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT tw.Category_ID, tc.NAME,
       COUNT(*) AS TotalCount, SUM(tw.IsPlayed=1) AS Played ,SUM(tw.IsPlayed=0) AS NonPlayed
FROM Table_Category  tc
INNER JOIN Table_Word tw 
ON tc.Category_ID = tw.Category_ID 
-- WHERE tw.IsPlayed=1
GROUP BY tc.Category_ID, tc.NAME
```

here `SUM(tw.IsPlayed=1) AS Played ,SUM(tw.IsPlayed=0) AS NonPlayed` is used ,so u will get the both  Played and non played

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from
(select categoryID, count(isPlayed), sum(isPlayed) from tblword group by categoryID) b
left join 
tblcategory a 
on a.categoryID = b.categoryID
```

I'd aggregate first, then join.

Comment: @milkey can we get only isPlayed=1 records by using above query ?

Comment: @Giri sum(isPlayed) represents the "count" of isPlayed=1 records.  You could also add it to a where clause on the inner select if you wished,  but then count and sum would give you the same value.